# How to display highcharts using highchartsJS in aspmvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I cannot display a chart when creating it with the following code:

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
```

however when i change it to this:

```
        $(function () {

        Create the chart
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                type: 'column',
                renderTo: 'container'
            },
```

it does display the graph.
My issue is that i need to display the graph in the first way for an additional java script method to run.

the code im working with comes from the following [example](http://jsfiddle.net/skTHx/22/):

Comment: What do you mean "cannot display"? Errors? It doesn't show up? These two should be equivalent.

Comment: Make sure you have up-to-date version of Highcharts (4.x or at least 3.x). As you can see, your demo works fine.

Comment: @ondkloss  by cannot display i mean the chart does not render to the container, so nothing is displayed. The demo works on js fiddle, but in my project where im using asp.net mvc i need to use the renderTo method. However when i do that i get the error: "uncaught typeError:$('#container').highcharts is not a function" when inspecting the source on run time. 
I am using the latest version.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem, instead of referencing jquery and highcharts at the top of the page i needed to reference it inside the bundle config and render it on a shared layout page.